# UWP App Error on creating

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, uwp

I am trying to create a UWP App with visual Studio. I keep getting this error message. Is there something i can do to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Some dlls are missing.. that is what it says in plain german... I would just do a repair for your Visual Studio installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most probably a corrupted Visual Studio installation. Let's just do a Visual Studio repair, or run the installer and make sure you update the "Universal Windows App Development Tools".

**Update:** (if that does not help)

Well, I looked into this in more detail: so the root cause is most probably that Microsoft removed Application Insights, but during an update the template file for UWP apps was not updated and the Application Insights reference is still there.

To fix it you have to remove it from the vstemplate file. On my machine the location of the file is this (should be similar on your machine…):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows Root\Windows UAP\1033\BlankApplication\BlankApplication.vstemplate
```

(Now as you see this vstemplate file is for the "Blank Application" template. If you have this problem with another project template then edit the corresponding vstemplate file)

Then first of all, make a backup copy of the file! Then open it and look for something like this (for the one with Application Insights):

```
<WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>Microsoft.VisualStudio.WinRT.TemplateWizards, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>Microsoft.VisualStudio.WinRT.TemplateWizards.ApplicationInsigths..Wizard</FullClassName>
  </WizardExtension>
```

And remove it.

Comment: Hey So I just finished the VS repair. Still getting the same problem though. Any other ideas?

Comment: To everyone who has the same problem, don't wate your time with repairing or uninstalling. The Updated solution works anything else doesnt.

Comment: Template is cached at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache\CSharp\Windows Root\Windows UAP\1033\BlankApplication`. You might need to edit that too.