# Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 issues with UWP apps

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I had VS2015 U2 properly installed and working properly.
after updating to VS2015 U3, UWP projects are not working properly and give the following errors :

Error when creating a UWP blank app
[image: Error when creating a UWP blank app]

Creating UWP app using MVVM light template
[image: Creating UWP app using MVVM light template]

I have removed all programs on my PC and downloaded again a new version of the VS2015 U3 (this time it is coming with Windows 14393 SDK) but the situation is worse now. 
any solution ?

Comment: Have you checked this question: [UWP App Error on creating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39531308/uwp-app-error-on-creating)? It seems that you are having the same issue. If this still doesn't work, I'd suggest you use [Visual Studio Uninstaller](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller) to clean up the system and then try to reinstall Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3.

Comment: Hello, I reinstalled my whole PC and installed VS2015 U3. Now when creating a project I can only target 10240 SDK and not 15586 or 14393. I tried running a UWP on my phone but it's getting deployment errors.

Comment: solved the deployment errors after fixing a problem with my memory card that had crashed on my phone. but the issue with VS 2015 not seeing SDK 1511 and 1607 is still there

Comment: Did you try to repair Visual Studio as well or just uninstall and reinstall?

Comment: I cleared all of the programs on my PC and I reinstalled VS2015 U3. I have solved the deployment issue on the phone as it was due to my memory card that had crashed. but I have not yet solved the issue with VS targeting only SDK 10240 and not higher

Answer (score 0):

try downloading microsoft web platform installer here is the link. It tells you what you need to download. I am not sure if it will work but give it a try.
https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx.

Comment: thank you. i will try that. isn't there a particular registery hack or a special trick to implement ?

Comment: There may be, I am not sure as I have never used it. But, web platform installer may solve your problem.

Comment: will do try that.

Comment: I cleaned my install and reinstalled VS2015. but it only targets SDK 10240